# Type hinting a non-generator (non-consumable) iterable

Tags: python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I'd like to type hint a function like this:

```
from types import Iterable

def func(thing: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    for i in range(10):
        for x in thing:
            do_thing(x)
```

PyCharm will (correctly) let me get away with passing in a generator to this function, but I want to type hint it in a way that it won't allow me to, while still accepting other iterables.

Using `Sequence[str]` isn't an option, iterables like KeyView aren't sequences, but I would still like to be able to include them.

Someone mentioned using a `Union` with a `Sequence` + `KeyView`, which would work, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant and universal solution

Of course, I could just convert `thing` to a `list` no matter what, but I'd rather just have this function type hinted correctly.

Using Python 3.7

Comment: Couldn't you use a union to include either a `Sequence` or a `KeyView`? I think you'd have to be using python 3.5+

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Comment: @chrisz Updated question to relfect your suggestion

Comment: Hmm. I'd guess that the most likely way you might one day be able to *approximately* express this is if the type hint syntax becomes sophisticated enough to let you express the type "an `Iterable`, but not an `Iterator`". In set notation, that'd be `Iterable \ Iterator` - the *"difference"* or [*"relative complement"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of the types `Iterable` and `Iterator`. Unfortunately, while we have `Union`s, we don't currently have any kind of complements or intersections, so that isn't (yet) expressable.

Comment: (Note that even if something like `Iterable \ Iterator` *does* one day become valid Python, it's perhaps an imperfect solution to this problem because it's possible to write a consumable `Iterable` which is nonetheless not an `Iterator`. Probably that's rare and a bad idea, though, so `Iterable \ Iterator`, *if* it ever becomes expressible, is probably what you'd want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is just not possible with Python's type system.

Straight from Guido ([source](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1319#issuecomment-1370300576)):

> Our type system doesn't allow you to express that -- it's like asking for any Animal except Cat. Adding an "except" clause like that to the type system would be a very difficult operation.
>
> Since there's no solution, I'm going to close this as "won't fix".

His [suggestion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1319#issuecomment-1365994733):

> Yeah, the practical solution is Sequence|Set|Mapping. The needed negation is years off.